# Calculus trig differentiation of $f(w) = 4\sin^{2}( \frac{w}{2})-\sin^{2}(w)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$
\begin{align}
 f(w) =& 4\sin^{2}\left( \frac{w}{2}\right)-\sin^{2}(w) \\
 f’(w) =& 8\sin\left(\frac{w}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{w}{2}\right)-2\sin w \cos w 
\end{align}
$$

Have I differentiated correctly?

The correct answer is

$ f’(w) = 2\sin(w)(1-\cos(w))$

Comment: no you need to differentiate $w/2$ too

Comment: Remember the chain rule. $w/2$ is also a function whose derivative is $1/2$

Comment: Oh right I see thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did a good job but forgot to differentiate $w/2$
$$f’(w) = 8\sin(w/2)\cos(w/2)\times \color{red}{\frac 12}-2\sin w \cos w$$

$$f’(w) = 4\sin(w/2)\cos(w/2)-2\sin w \cos w$$
$$f’(w) = 2\sin(w)-2\sin(w) \cos(w)$$
$$f’(w) = 2\sin(w)(1-\cos(w))$$

Answer (score 0):

In the first part you differentiated correctly w.r.t. $w/2$ which when differentiated again w.r.t. $w$ in a chain rule needed to be to multiplied with $\dfrac12$.. that you have missed. All else is fine.